# How to config the Nginx, then it can provide the Django's media resources?

Tags: django, nginx

How to config the Nginx, then it can provide the Django/Django-Rest-Framework's media resources?

In my remote CentOS-7 Server after I distributed my Django/Django-Rest-Framework project, I can not access the `media` and `static` resources by my API.

How can I config the Nginx, so I can access them?

I tried in nginx's `vhosts_backend.conf`, but did not success.

```
server {

    listen 8000;
    server_name 103.20.12.76;

    access_log /data/ldl/logs/103.20.12.76.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html/website/backend/;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }

     location ~ /media/*\.(jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif|swf)$
        {
            access_log off;
            expires 30d;
            root /var/www/html/python_backend/myProject;
            break;
        }

    location /media/ {

           root /data/ldl/repo/myProject/;
        }

    location /static/ {
            root /data/ldl/repo/myProject/;
        }

}
```

---

**EDIT-1**

My Django/Django-Rest-Framework project only provide the APIs, not the template views. and it use the `8000` port.
so I am looking for a way in Nginx to access the media and static resources like this:

http://103.20.12.76:8000/media/images/qiyun_admin_websitemanage/logo/logo_01_YGE3YKm.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [alias](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) . Here is an example:

```
 location /media {
        alias /data/ldl/repo/myProject/media;
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;
    }
```

And here is a full working example of a live site:

```
# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.server.example server.example;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl http2;
   server_name server.example;
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.example/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.example/privkey.pem;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
   ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
   ssl_session_timeout 1d;
   ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
   ssl_stapling on;
   ssl_stapling_verify on;
   add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
   ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
   ssl_session_tickets off;
   add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
   add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

   charset utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    expires $expires; 

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/server_access.log timed;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/server_error.log;


    location /media {
        alias /home/proj/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/proj/static;
    access_log off;
        expires 30d;
        ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one
        ## fell swoop.
        tcp_nodelay off;
        ## Set the OS file cache.
        open_file_cache max=3000 inactive=120s;
        open_file_cache_valid 45s;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
        open_file_cache_errors off;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass unix:///run/server.sock;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried but do not work. I don't know where is the error, can you tell me about this?

Comment: I think there is another issue, you are using two `/media/`  location block. Try to use one block. I also updated the answer.